# Outlook tasks masked as completed (using gmail as mail server)?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap

When I used Outlook tasks and mark a task as "Completed", it disappears from the list. When I use the Tasks view "Completed", this is empty even though I have marked numerous tasks as complete. I also cannot mark tasks with a due date (right-clicking only has options "Mark Complete" or "Clear Flag".

I think this is because we are using Gmail for business as our mail server, and Outlook is using the reduced functionality of Gmail which only has "Starred/Unstarred."

Is it possible to use the full Outlook tasks capabilities with Gmail as mail server? 
(I have enabled IMAP in Gmail settings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this Microsoft Office article, it is not possible: Google IMAP supports Mail in Outlook but **not** Contacts, Calendar, **Tasks**, and Notes:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Sync-basics-what-you-can-and-cannot-sync-5537D587-4930-4AC2-B044-3568509B1294

Answer (score 1):

Disappear from To-Do list or task folder?

If you've set a filter, completed tasks may be filtered. Please click View > View Settings. Turn off Filter.
[image]

You can refer to this official article: [Show all tasks marked complete](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/show-all-tasks-marked-complete-1b411fe4-f45b-4559-816f-e5a9bee87ba0)

Comment: Thanks, yes the filter is off and when I follow the instructions in to view tasks masked as completed it shows an empty list (even though it should not.)

Comment: Can you search Task folder and find these tasks marked as completed?

Comment: My Tasks > To-Do List is full of unfinished tasks, when marked as complete they disappear and do not reappear in "Completed", My Tasks > Tasks is empty

Comment: If this is not a view setting issue, you may test this in a new profile. This will help check if it lies on personal settings or corrupted data file